# difference between MBR and disk label

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, mbr

Is MBR/partition table = disk label ?

I read about about the description of disk label as

> The first sector of a disk that contains disk geometry and partition
> information.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5093/6mkisoq4v/index.html

[image]

And what I read talks about EFI and VTOC (Volume Table of Contents), e.g.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7228/6j6q7uet6/index.html

> About Disk Labels
>
> A special area of every disk is set aside for storing information about the disk's controller, geometry, and slices. That information is
> called the disk's label. Another term used to described the disk label
> is the VTOC (Volume Table of Contents).

But isn't MBR considered to be a disk label too since it is on the 1st sector of a disk as well ?

What is the difference between MBR and VTOC?

Comment: Include your source. I'll include it since I googled it. But you should have included it

Comment: MBR is PC terminology.  The doc you mention is generic computer terminology (e.g. mainframe or data processing).  The MBR is not a disk label, since typically there is nothing unique and specific to identify the HDD/SSD.  MSDOS and Windows treats each partition (defined by the MBR's Partition Table) as a volume.  The last time I heard of VTOC was a long time ago for magnetic tape.

Comment: @sawdust  You may be right, but every answer has stated that disklabel and MBR do the same thing. You're saying that's not true or not entirely true, because disdklabel identifies the drive as well.  Do you have a source?

Comment: @barlop -- "Disk label" has no definition in the PC world (i.e. MS Windows doesn't officially use that term), so you can use it any way you want.  That quoted Oracle doc has a generalized/universal definition to ensure it includes the concept of MBR.  But ask any "PC expert" *"What's a disk label?"*, and you'll probably not get consistent answers (e.g. MBR, partition table, volume label, etc.).

Comment: @sawdust  Windoes doesn't use the term "disklabel", but clearly other Oss do, and since there is such a thing as what you call "generic computer terminology"   Any generic computer terminology can be applied to a computer, including a windows machine.  Can you give an example of a system that uses a def of disklabel that would exclude MS-DOS's MBR, vs a system that uses a definition of disklabel that would include MS-DOS's MBR? Before, you made a statement that disklabel would exclude MS-DOS's MBR,n your reason was that it has to uniquely identify the disk. Every1 else says it'd include it

Comment: dear all - i have posted another related thread - http://superuser.com/questions/988230/1st-sector-on-a-disk-vs-1st-sector-on-a-partition - hope to hear from you

Comment: @barlop -- Your *"every1 else"* is composed of two or three users.  I wonder if any of them used a HDD that was not a PC-compatible drive.  I've worked in data-centers that used multi-platter disk packs that would be mounted into floor-standing drives (Storage Module Drives).  These [minicomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicomputer) systems used proprietary OSes, and the disk packs probably had some kind of disk label that had nothing to do with MBR (since the IBM PC didn't even exist yet).

Comment: @sawdust well, by everyone else, I meant the ones that replied (the two - as of writing).  I don't think any of them are denying the existence of disklabels very different to the MBR and preceding the MBR.  Linux or BSD has a disk label very different to the MBR but it doesn't necessarily follow that the MBR is not a disklabel in the/a generic definition of disklabel, and apparently disklabel is a generic thing.  If you were to show that disklabel is not a generically defined thing, or that the definition of disklabel is generic but(conceptually) excludes MBR, then you'd have a good case.

Comment: *"A special area of every disk is set aside for storing information about the disk's controller, ..."* -- This definition belies its PC-centricity, since IDE disk drives are a PC-industry product.  Before these PC HDDs, the disk controller was electronics completely separate from the drive, so there was no reason to put controller info into a "disk label".

Comment: @"barlop -- You could make the definition of "disk label" so broad (e.g. "it's the first sector of a disk") to encompass the MBR, that you obliterate the meaning of "label".  There is typically no "label" or disk identification in a MBR.  It's like saying that a "person" is a type of "animal", so let's give every "animal" the right to vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "disklabel" defines the boundaries of sections of the hard drive.  The MBR does this same thing.  The GPT format does the same thing.  They are different ways to do the same thing.

Here's an analogy: it is like having a text file that says:

> Prefix=Mr. FirstName=George LastName=Washington

and another file that says:

> [FamilyName:Washington] [FirstName:George] [Gender:Male]

Both descriptions provide essentially the same details about the person, but the technical ways that it is done are a bit different.

If you use a BSD operating system, it will likely rely mostly on the BSD disklabel.  (In fact, some software will call the BSD disklabel a "bsdlabel".)  If you use Microsoft Windows, you're more likely to rely more on the information in the MBR.  (I'm not commenting much on what supports GPT, since it is newer and, as I write this, specific details about support have been changing over the years.  Basically, though, the GPT is another way to record the same sort of information.)

The BSD disklabel can co-exist alongside with the MBR.  Both the BSD disklabel and the MBR describe boundaries; these are separate descriptions, so they don't affect each other.  (It only makes sense to have both of these descriptions provide identical values for the details.  If the different descriptions are providing different values, that would be confusing because there would be some question about which record is more trustworthy)

Which one do you want to use?  Well, if you're using a hard drive over 2TB, the answer is not MBR.  (It may be GPT.)  Beyond that, the answer is probably going to depend on what operating system you're using.  If you use multiple operating systems, you might use both.

Comment: Great answer. This terminology confused me when many (15) years ago I downloaded a FreeBSD ISO and printed the Handbook in an Internet café to install on a laptop at home. After that experiment, I went back to GNU/Linux distributions but life would have been much easier had I had access to sites such as this one.

Comment: @TOOGAM why does it make sense to have both description providing identical details ?  - can you elaborate further ?

Comment: Didn't mean to imply that this makes a lot of sense.  This is, simply, the reality.  It is how things are. sensible or not.  But, there is some reasoning.  BSD is based on some older Unix code which wasn't designed for home PC use; MBR was made by IBM and Microsoft.  So then fast forward to today, you have things like FreeBSD that support BSD labels (to do things in a way that works in a way that is consistent with BSD on all kinds of hardware) and MBR (to do things in a way that works in a way consistent with other operating systems on the PC architecture).  [Standards](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: @TOOGAM - thanks for your feedback - i have posted another related thread http://superuser.com/questions/988230/1st-sector-on-a-disk-vs-1st-sector-on-a-partition - hope to hear from you

Comment: You write "The BSD disklabel can co-exist alongside with the MBR" <--- what do you mean?  Do you mean a hard disk can have 2 partition tables?  can you give an example 'cos i've never heard of that before, though i'm no expert.

Comment: @barlop Yes.  [Wikipedia's page on "BSD disklabel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_disklabel) says that on IBM-compatible PCs, "the BSD partitioning scheme is nested within a single, primary, MBR partition"... So the MBR is in the first sector, and the MBR specifies where a primary partition starts, and then the BSD disklabel is written inside a primary partition.  The result is information about the partitions is stored in multiple locations on the same disk.  On a side note, "logical drives" in "extended partitions" stores partition info on multiple sectors.

Comment: @TOOGAM but aren't MBR partition table layout and BSD partition table layout alternatives.. So how can one be in the other?

Comment: You're not forced to choose one or the other.  Both may be used.  An MBR-based PC starts by running code from the MBR's first 446 bytes.  After those bytes are 64 bytes which are the standard location for defining an MBR's primary partitions.  The code from the MBR's first 446 bytes starts to run code found in one of the primary partitions.  If that code is a BSD operating system, then it follows the BSD standard and looks for a BSD disklabel within the primary partition.  BSD then trusts the details from the BSD disklabel, and starts to completely ignore the MBR.  There's no conflict.

Answer (score 5):

"Disklabel" is a generic term for the block of information which describes the disk's structure (partitions and sometimes boot information).

PCs usually use either the MBR (aka "MS-DOS") format disklabel, or the newer GPT one. (Older BSD systems also have their own disklabel format, which either replaces MBR or is nested inside it.) Earlier Mac computers used to use "Apple Partition Map" (APM).

Comment: How does a BSD system have its disklabel "nested" inside MBR ?  do you mean nested in 1 of its partition instead ?

Comment: Noob: The MBR defines partitions.  Then, the disklabel also gets stored somewhere... I'm not offhand 100% certain if it is in one of the partitions, but I suppose that is one possibility.  I do know that it is not stored in the MBR.  There isn't room!  The MBR is small.  So the disklabel must be getting stored somewhere else.

Comment: @TOOGAM doesn't what you said differ with the answer given by grawity?  you're suggesting they're stored in different places. But grawity described MBR as a format of disklabel. Also, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120221/gpt-or-mbr-how-do-i-know  describes disklabel as the general term, and specific types of disklabel examples being MBR, GPT, e.t.c..

Comment: @barlop Yes, my usage of the term "disklabel" is different than how grawity (and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210921/97078)) used it.  I referred to the term "disklabel" as a "BSD disklabel" (also called a "bsdlabel") like what gets created by BSD's "disklabel" command.  So my answers were referring to a specific way of describing the partition layout.  The other quotes you point out used the term "disklabel" in a more generic way, as a more general term.  For such general usage, I prefer to say "partition layout", to be less likely to cause confusion by people who may use BSD disks.

Comment: @TOOGAM so if bsd disklabel and MBR are different partition layouts, then why do you seem to be saying that disklabel might be stored in one of the partitions and that it is too big to fit in the MBR.  Why would there even be a question of a disklabel (whether in the generic sense or the specific bsd disklabel sense), fitting into the MBR?

Comment: The BSD "disklabel" program asks for "mount point" locations.  After this "disklabel" program writes, exits, is run again, and reads from disk, it can show these locations.  The MBR's primary partition table is only 64 bytes (16 per partition, times 4 partitions), seemingly not big enough to store the partition boundaries and the mount point data that the disklabel program shows.  Also, the disklabel can store information about more than 4 "mount points", unlike MBR partitions.  [Wikip'](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_disklabel) says bsdlabel "is nested within a single, primary, MBR partition"